# Different ways to approximate date a value is reached

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm creating a spreadsheet to track progress to a goal: Spreadsheet with day and data values[image]

I would like to have a projected date a value is reached.

I learned about functions such as FORECAST or TREND, but while they give me data that I want, these functions appear to require a range and won't accept a single value (e.g.  `=TREND(A4, C4, 1000000)` will not work)
I want to have a projected date to a goal (such as 1,000,000) that can start from D2. Is this possible?

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question [useless for others](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) or images, which are [hard to copy](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Comment: The more the known data, the more accurate the projection will be. Why do you want projection per day?